# vim: is possible to use mouse to move lines around

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, mouse, edit

**Question:**

Is possible to use mouse to move lines around?

**Requirements & Clarification**

1. I do know keyboard solutions.

- normal mode `ddp` `d2j'}p` `dapggp` alike.
- cmdline commands, `:co.` `'<,'>m'a` etc.

2. I want this feature -- mouse to move/duplicate/delete lines -- mainly for simple use (do not exceed one page). Here is the workflow, with example of copying vim 8.0 feature from [Vim 8.0 is released - Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/vim-8-0-is-released)

- between chrome and gvim
- copy in chrome
- back to gvim, paste
- `nn <buffer> <Tab> p` to facilitate the workflow
- but here is the problem, some line are are whole line, some are not.

The result is like below

```
Asynchronous I/O support, channels
Jobs

Timers
Partials
Lambda and Closure
Packages

New style tests

Window IDs
```

In this case, it is more sensible to move lines with mouse.

Of course I can `vG:g/^$/d` to remove empty lines afterwards.

But I wonder is it possible to move/copy/delete lines with mouse,
If possible, I'am also interested to how you community think about
the api interface if to create a such plugin.

**== Edit ==**

step 1, selection

- double left click select current line
- with left mouse press, move mouse do selection.

this part is already doen if `set mouse=a`
though the behavior is a little different

- double click select current word
- triple click select current line
- the same as stated above

step 2, duplicate or move selected line.

- with above step, we are at visual mode.
- how to move the selected line?

Possible implementation of feature list

- right click to move selected lines at line that mouse click.
- with right mouse pressed, contiguously move select lines, maybe use hook on mouse event.
- right double click to duplicate selected line under line that mouse click.

In summary,
***how to achive this step 2, this is main point of my question.*** As for the mouse, someone may prefer use middle click or scrolled instead.

Comment: I re-read your question a few times and I still can't tell exactly what you want to accomplish... Why do you refer to an external page? Can you show a "before" and "after" of what you want to do? Why do you think using the mouse would be more efficient? What do you have in mind, using right-click for a pop-up menu, or drag and drop, or just click here and there to move a line there? Please [edit] the question, try to simplify it and keep it focused. Thanks!

Comment: As for why mouse in this case more efficient, since my right hand hold mouse to select text in browser, left hand <Alt-Tab> to switch program. use mouse is faster than, since its just one click to move a line above, and the cursor is already there.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need to move lines around if it's just copy and paste from the browser, but (1) you can remap <LeftMouse> and <RightMouse>; (2) you can map such that empty lines are removed after each paste.